# Accept keyboard shortcuts in pyGTK

Tags: pygtk, xlib

I would like to be able to have a keyboard shortcut to do a certain thing, like CTRL+O, or something else...

xlib or pyGTK will work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [gtk.AccelGroup](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkaccelgroup.html) class (PyGTK) might be a good place to start. There are some examples in [Virtaal](http://virtaal.org/)'s source ([1](https://translate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/translate/src/trunk/virtaal/virtaal/views/mainview.py) [2](https://translate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/translate/src/trunk/virtaal/virtaal/views/storeview.py) [3](https://translate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/translate/src/trunk/virtaal/virtaal/views/unitview.py) and more around the [source](https://translate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/translate/src/trunk/virtaal/virtaal/)).